# Sliding background

Tags: css

I am new to CSS, I am trying to make a background and main content remain centered as you shrink the browser like this site http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/ If you widen the browser over two screens, the background remains central and the same size and the margins increase to fill the space, but when you shrink it, the background remains centered to (what I assume is) a minimum size before it fixes left, in other words both sides of the background image are pushed out of view up to a point. Hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

They're using `background-position:center;` to place the background in the middle of the screen. When the browser window is smaller than the background image, it is clipped. When the browser window grows larger than the image, it stays in the center. The image edges fade into the background colour of the body, so that it gives the impression of being part of the background.

Comment: I'd probably recommend `background-position: 50% 0;`

Comment: I'd say the use of `center` is more descriptive. Or, even better, `background-position: center top;`

Comment: We're really splitting hairs here... haha

Comment: Indeed. I guess `50% 0` is more literal, whereas `center top` is more descriptive. I suppose it's whichever style you prefer.

Comment: Thanks Polynomial - searched for hours how to sort such a simple thing"